# Update markers without updating Google Maps center with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm using `react-google-maps v9.4.5` library. When I update the markers, the center of the map is also updated. How to update the markers without affecting the map?

I already tried with redux and also updating the state.

I tried the example from here: https://codesandbox.io/s/qzj7qp4p2w?file=/src/Map.js

But it doesn't recognize the variable **google** that I use in Markers.js

`GoogleMaps.js`

```
import React from "react";
import {
    withGoogleMap,
    GoogleMap,
    Marker,
    withScriptjs
} from "react-google-maps";

import Markers from "./Markers";

class GoogleMaps extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <GoogleMap
                zoom={this.props.zoom}
                center={this.props.center}>
                //My own component
                <Markers markers={this.props.markers}/>
            </GoogleMap>
        );
    }
}

export default withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(GoogleMaps));
```

`Markers.js`

```
import React from "react";
import {
    Marker,
} from "react-google-maps";

export default function Markers(props) {
    const google = window.google;
    return (
        <>
            {
                props.markers.map((marker, index) => (
                    <Marker
                        key={index} position={{lat: marker.lat, lng: marker.lng}}
                        icon={{
                                url: marker.icon,
                                size: new google.maps.Size(32, 32),
                            }}
                    />
                ))
            }
        </>
    );
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

It was my fault, just replace `center` with `defaultCenter` and it worked.